# Read .txt files inside OpenCV 's glob c++

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I'm currently using OpenCV 3.1's glob to store all my .txt files.

My aim is to read line by line those stored .txt files.

So far I successfully stored all my .txt files in my "posFn"

Unfortunately I can't read the each txt inside posFn.

```
int main(int, char**){

// Get Pos and Neg Samples Path
string training_path = "/home/TrainingDataSet";
string pos_samp_path = training_path + "/pos/";
string neg_samp_path = training_path + "/neg/";

// Set Pos and Neg vectors
vector<String> posFn;
glob(pos_samp_path,posFn,false);

vector<int> posVect;
ifstream openTxt;
string str;

for(int i = 0; i<posFn.size(); i++){
    openTxt.open(posFn[i].c_str());

    if(openTxt.is_open()){
        while(openTxt>>str){
            posVect.push_back(stoi(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see posFn stored all the .txt's.
[image]

I can't read txt files inside posFn.
I mean

```
posVect.push_back(stoi(str));
```

is not executed.
I also tried

```
while( getline(openTxt,str) ){
    posVect.push_back(stoi(str)); 
}
```

But still not working.
This could be because opencv's String may be different from std::string, but even if I use String str, instead of string str, I can't execute

```
posVect.push_back(stoi(str));
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using OpenCV's glob, using glob solved the issue.

Step1: Include glob header library

```
#include <glob.h>
```

Step2: Define glob_t variable

```
glob_t glob_result;
```

Step3: Use glob function to load all files to glob_t variable

```
// pos_samp_path is positive sample path directory
// I.e. pos_samp_path="/home/PositivePath/*.txt";
glob(pos_samp_path.c_str(),GLOB_TILDE,NULL,&glob_result);
```

Step4: Read files w/ ifstream object

```
// int histVal = 0;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<glob_result.gl_pathc;++i){
    ifstream file(string(glob_result.gl_pathv[i]));
    while(file >> histVal){
        posVect.push_back(histVal);
    }
}
```

Finally all variables inside your folder, will be in your posVect vector
Declaration of posVect is:

```
vector<int> posVect;
```